# converting an API response object into a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get a response from a 3rd party API and convert it to a list.

I am getting this error on the line below where I assign the results to 'returnValue'.

I made sure to include the 'using System.Linq;' directive.

Here is the error:

> 'ListCharacterResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

```
public List<T> RetrieveCharacterListFromApi<T>(Guid gameId)
{
    List<T> returnValue = default(List<T>);
    var getCharacterResponse = GetCharacters(gameId);
    var results = getCharacterResponse.Result;
    // 'ListCharacterResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'.
    returnValue = results.ToList<T>();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Here is where I connect to the 3rd party API where it returns a 
**ListCharacterResponse** object:

```
public async Task<ListCharacterResponse> GetCharacters(Guid gameId)
{
    ListCharacterResponse response;
    response = await charMgr.GetCharactersListAsync(gameId);
    return response;
}
```

I use RetrieveCharacterListFromApi like this in a .net controller:

```
Guid gameId;
var characters = new List<Character>();
characters = API.RetrieveCharacterListFromApi<Character>(gameId);
```

Is there another way to convert it to a List?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect that to exist? Look at the response class and see what it has.

Comment: @SLaks well it doesn't unfortunately.  I guess I was hoping for a way to manually create the list?  I'm not sure.  I've never encountered an issue like this before.

Comment: well, the return type of your GetCharacters is not a list, it is a ListCharacterResponse once you get the final result. Thus as far as the code is concerned, it is a singular object. Odds are you have to manually build your list. Or, make sure your GetCharacterLystAsync method actually returns a List (i assume it doesn't since it doesn't complain about incompatible types)

Comment: if ListCharacterResponse is a Collection sort of, you can try returnValue=new List(results);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results from the API call are in `Character` format, then you're basically there.  Instead of the `.ToList<T>()` you could:

```
public List<T> RetrieveCharacterListFromApi<T>(Guid gameId)
{
    // List<T> returnValue = default(List<T>);
    var getCharacterResponse = GetCharacters(gameId);
    var results = getCharacterResponse.Result;
    // 'ListCharacterResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'.
    List<T> returnValue = new List<T>(results);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Or, if you need to iterate:

```
public List<T> RetrieveCharacterListFromApi<T>(Guid gameId)
{
    List<T> returnValue = default(List<T>);
    var getCharacterResponse = GetCharacters(gameId);
    var results = getCharacterResponse.Result;
    // 'ListCharacterResponse' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'.
    foreach(Character character in results)
        returnValue.Add(character);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Luke, I tried to iterate, but I get this error: 
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type ListCharacterResponse because ListCharacterResponse does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: If that's the case then I'm afraid @SomeStudent is right. The response you're getting is not in a format that is able to be iterated upon. If you have no control over the format you are receiving from the API, then at this point I believe you're stuck manually creating the list (some options would be: make a new model accurately reflecting ListCharacterResponse with a constructor that extracts properties from the object and formats them into a ```List<Character>``` format, Dictionary or ExpandoObjects, etc.)

Comment: I inspected the running code in Visual Studio and I can see that results looks like this: Api.Character[10] for one of the calls. So does that mean it's an array?

Comment: Oh I think I see the problem.  The Response is an object with an array, plus 2 other fields (an int, and a string).

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell glad you found it! I'm also glad the object is able to be iterated upon as well - that makes your job much easier :-)